# Delayed_Paperclip job complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, resque, delay

I am currently using delayed and it is up and running successfully. However, I can't seem to add a hook for when the jobs are completed from resque. The code I have currently is listening to the correct queue, but still seems to not work. I might be making a very simple, stupid mistake, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the model (working fine as far as I can see):

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :approved, :entry_text, :reviewed, :user_id, :photo

  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "250x250", :large => "500x500>" },
    :url => "link-to-s3-will-be-env-var",
    :path => "path/:id/:basename.:extension"

  process_in_background :photo

end
```

And then my little worker class (the part that doesn't seem to be run)

```
class PhotoProcessor
    @queue = :paperclip
    def self.perform(photo_id)

        puts "*****************OMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMGOMG*********************"
        puts photo_id.inspect
    end
end
```

I can't get it to output the crazy string, just for testing purposes, but I can't even seem to have this method called. Thanks for any help, I am clearly missing something obvious.

Comment: Shoudn't it be `self.perform` instead of `self.done_working` not sure of `delayed_job` though but resque act on `perform` action AFAIK

Comment: I had self.perform originally, but it never got called and my garbage string never came out. I assumed that it was because the delayed_paperclip gem was handling the self.perform but I could be wrong.

I wanted the method self.done_working() to be referenced when the Resque worker was completed (reference:http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/j/jerefrer-resque-1.1.0/Resque/Worker.html#method-i-done_working), but I could just be referencing the method incorrectly.

Comment: hmm well the doc is correct `done_working` is part of Resque::Worker and not of Job as you have written that y I told you that resque used `.perform` check [here](https://github.com/meetme2meat/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/worker.rb#L178) perhaps the done_working you are looking at is [here](https://github.com/meetme2meat/resque/blob/master/lib/resque/worker.rb#L415-L418)

Comment: nope the gem sure has it own perform action but it has nowhere to do with the perform action written inside the above code since gem internally call the `enqueue` command like we traditionally do so `perform` method instead of `done_working` should be respond by resque

Comment: It might be my own lack of knowledge in what the gem is actually doing, but shouldn't my worker be catching the enqueue if, like they say, they are pushing the job onto the queue paperclip? I still cannot get my garbage output to display in console even with self.perform. I am a bit lost, if you couldn't' tell already.